# Create admin user that can authenticate to any database (even those that do not exist yet)

Tags: mongodb, authentication

I am trying to make an admin user, which can authenticate to any database. When I do something like this:

```
db.createUser({
    "user": "admin", 
    "pwd": "adminPassword", 
    "roles": [
        "userAdminAnyDatabase", 
        "dbAdminAnyDatabase", 
        "readWriteAnyDatabase"
    ]
});
```

It works fine when connecting to the `admin` database. However, it doesn't work when I try something like this: `mongodb://admin:adminPassword@localhost:27017/someDatabaseHere`. I cannot authenticate to `someDatabaseHere` unless I authenticate to the admin database first, then go change stuff around in `someDatabaseHere` afterwards.

I really want to get the URI working as above, without needing to create an user for each database afterwards.

Alternatively, I would like to authenticate locally without credentials (simply `mongodb://localhost:27017/someDatabaseHere`) but require credentials remotely. That could work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> unless I authenticate to the admin database first, then go change stuff around in someDatabaseHere afterwards.

Currently (as of MongoDB 3.4.10), this is how the authentication mechanism works. This is the purpose of the [`--authenticationDatabase` parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-authenticationdatabase). If the user is defined in the `admin` database, then it should have access to all databases on the server, existing or not.

> I would like to authenticate locally without credentials

Currently this is not possible, since MongoDB uses a role-based authentication scheme and not IP-based authentication.